# How to implement push provision api?

Tags: android-pay, google-pay, android-tap-and-pay

I have implemented the Push Provisioning API using Google Tap and pay client.

While querying linking token I am facing the below exception.

```
W/System.err: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 15009: Calling package not verified
```

I have tried to create signed apk and install, but still same issue

Anybody help me out to unblock me?

Answer (score 0):

that error occurs when you don't have access to push provisioning API.

You can see it on the troubleshooting page:
https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/apis/push-provisioning/android/support/troubleshooting?authuser=1

To solve this you need to ask access for Push Provisioning API. Google has to identify your application as well as its version(production, development, debug). Versions as you know are differentiated by the key that signs them. Generate the correct version of your app gets its SHA 256 fingerprint and provide it in the aforementioned form.

Here are the instructions:
https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/apis/push-provisioning/android/allowlist?authuser=1

Key used to sing your app on the Play Store maybe different than the one you use locally to generate signed apps. Also Debug versions take the default key from .android directory(you can find other stack overflow posts that provide information about debug keys and their credentials.)